# I imput alt tags on all my Images but it is only showing up on the first image?

Tags: image, tags

I have put in a number of Products with 3 Images on Magento. I have filled in the Label section ( Alt Text ) on all 3 images and uploaded the images. When I run a website check 2 of the images say they have no Alt Text. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What images are you talking about? Is this product images or other images?